# Yii code generator password not working

Tags: mysql, yii, nginx, centos

This is my first Yii site. Everything was good until i tried Yii code generator. I can successfully open Yii code generator page. But when i enter password (set in config/main.php) it just reloads the page and shows the login page again. This always happen when i enter correct password. When i enter wrong password it says "Incorrect password".

Im not sure if its because of mysql connection problem. Mysql is running fine i tried creating and accessing DB table using shell and all worked as expected.

Im running Centos 6, nginx and mysql.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
This is my gii config part:

```
'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'ghostrider',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        //'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1'),
    ),
```

Thanks!

Solved:
Making 
    'password'=>false
bypasses the authentication screen. Thnx to jonny for this great suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean the Gii code generator?

Comment: Yup Gii code generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'password'=>false,`

In your config that should mean no password is needed and it should just load

```
'gii'=>array(
'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
'password'=>false,
//If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only.
'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
),
```

Also, you need to make sure that it is uncommented too

Comment: thnx for your response. Sorry! but i can't see any password=>false option and if password is set to false should it still show login page when i go to index.php?r=gii link?

Comment: ok its working now. But i had to set passoword=>false Under 'gii'=>array option, same as you mentioned and no enter password page this time. But when i remove password=>false line same problem persists. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Gii works from the config file only. It doesn't have anything to do with MySql passwords. What you set the password for Gii in the config is the password you use to log into Gii.

Comment: yes, that part i understand. The password for Gii that i set in config should work on the code generator page but so far it isn't working, when i ener correct password it simply reload the ENTER PASSWORD page.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your rules? in the 'urlManager'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34260/discussion-between-jonnny-and-aaqib-iqbal)